# How to query circular data?

Tags: mysql, circular-reference

I am trying to calculate how much a currency conversion in PayPal costs. For one currency conversion I receive two entries from PayPal, I imported them into a table paypal_transaction:

Simplified, the table looks like this:

paypal_transaction

| transaction_id | transaction_id_2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| B | A | 20 |
| C | D | 30 |
| D | C | 40 |

What I want is a list like this where I have the two connected transactions in one line:

| transaction_id | transaction_id_2 | value_tid1 | value_tid2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 | 20 |
| C | D | 30 | 40 |

But what I get is:

| transaction_id | transaction_id_2 | value_tid1 | value_tid2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 | 20 |
| B | A | 20 | 10 |
| C | D | 30 | 40 |
| D | C | 40 | 30 |

The issue is that the entries reference each other (circular) and so I kinda get "duplicates".

For some reason I wasn't able to add a comment, so in reply to ysth: there is no "master" id, both IDs are one of a pair. That is exactly my problem. I want one line per "ID pair". It does not matter which of the two IDs, or both, are in that line.

I also cannot answer my question, stockoverflow does not seem to like my browser, so:
THANK YOU, LUUK!! transaction_id < transaction_id_2 does the trick!

Comment: how do you want to determine which of the two ids to show in transaction_id

Comment: You have to decide how you will make the difference, you could do that by selecting only those lines that have `value_tid1 < value_tid2`, or another approach could be `transaction_id < transaction_id_2`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the rows

```
select a.transaction_id, b.transaction_id, a.value, b.value
from paypal_transaction a
inner join paypal_transaction b on a.transaction_id_2 = b.transaction_id
```

Add where clasuse according to your requirement